# Android: vertically stretching buttons

Tags: android, layout, button, stretch

I have an application in which there are two buttons side-by-side at the bottom (in a TableLayout inside a RelativeLayout). This looks fine on small screens, but on larger screens there is an ugly black space left at the bottom. I want to expand the buttons vertically to fill the space, but can't work out how!

I've included the code below (with the contents of the RelativeLayout removed for simplicity; the below behaves in exactly the same way as the version with it)

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="@string/Button01" android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="@string/Button02" android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone have any idea how to stretch the buttons in the current layout, or a different layout that will allow me to do this more easily?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little (lot) more experimentation, it turns out that I was approaching this the wrong way. By removing the TableLayout, and replacing it with a LinearLayout the fill_parent attribute for height started working as expected, and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

As your within a relative layout could you not use the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom='true'` and force the bottom edge of the buttons to align with the bottom edge of the layout? You could apply bottom margin to leave some gap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I managed to stumble across a solution with LinearLayouts that sorted things out. Thanks anyway!